# How can I send multiple documents to elastic with one API call

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic and I need a way to push multiple documents to Elastic by only making one call to `POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/`.

The body schema looks like this:

```
{ 
"docs": [ 
{ "_source": {"message":"message1"} }, 
{ "_source": {"message":"message2"} } 
] 
}
```

I tried with the ingest API and Pipelines with no luck.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, both of you @JinLee and @NishantSaini for helping me. I want to document what I did.

First, add `/_bulk` endpoint. So the API call is now: `POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_bulk`.

Now set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-ndjson`

Then the body must be like this:

```
{"index":{}}
{"message":"message1"}
{"index":{}}
{"message":"message2"}
```

And now everything works!

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is **Bulk API** which lets you perform many index/delete operations in a single API call, thus increasing indexing speed. Here is the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

So what you can do is

`POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk`
`POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/_bulk`
`POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_bulk`

try one of these with the body contents of yours, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Body content has to be changed but your endpoints really worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Agus  Good to hear bro~ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/docs-bulk.html) to do so.

Eg:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"1"}}
{"field1":"field 1 data 1","field2":11}
{"index":{"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"2"}}
{"field1":"field 1 data 2","field2":21}
```

In you case this will translate to:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"myindex","_type":"mytype"}}
{"message":"message1"}
{"index":{"_index":"myindex","_type":"mytype"}}
{"message":"message2"}
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. Your hint about body translation really helped me.

Comment: Glad it helped.