# I have a data file.I want to insert that data in to elastic search- kibana. Is there any automated way I can do this?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

I have a data file.I want to insert that data in to elastic search- kibana. Is there any automated way I can do this?

link - deliver-events-to-s3-7-2019-06-04-03-49-01-5df38ba9-86c0-4860-b51f-2c0d30132d6f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. In your Kibana, You will see the menu called 'Machine Learning'.  Click~!

[image]

## 2. Go to 'Data Visualizer' and click 'Upload file'.

[image]

## 3. Drag your file here.

[image]

## 4. And then click 'Import' at the bottom.

[image]

## 5. Type an index name. And Import~!

[image]

## 6. Finally, view your index.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got it.

Comment: Can I automate this process ? so that I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: @Learner007  If you use Beats to collect data, you don't need to put them manually into Elasticsearch. However, if you want to put data into Elasticsearch with data files, you need to put data manually. Above proocess already made putting data into Elasticsearch easy. (AI)

Comment: If I want to insert two files in same index what should I do?

Comment: @Learner007 Hmm I've never done it. But I think you put one file in index and add another using bulk api using dev console. I'm not an expert, just a beginner. It's just my guess :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/55769048/10504469 (This might help you)